# How Spring framework checks if the user account is expired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I can see this html page: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AccountExpiredException.html

In my code, I am using the following:

```
 try {
providerManager.authenticate(auth);
} catch(LockedException e) {
    // some user exception to throw
} catch(DisabledException e) {
    // some user exception to throw
} catch(AccountExpiredException e) {
    // some user exception to throw
}
```

So how Spring determines about user account expired?

I have to do testing and so I have to expire the user account. That's why.

Comment: By calling the `isNotExpired` method on the `User`. However why are you even testing this and throwing separate exceptions? Feels like you are working around the exception handling of Spring Security and with that expose important information to users (i.e. account locked, expired etc.) which again is valuable information for hackers.

Comment: `isNotExpired` is the getter method. But what about the setter method which sets the expired variable to TRUE under which condition does it sets it to TRUE? I just want to give the user, a specific reason of there acount being expired. No other information other than that which can cause hack kind.

Comment: Exposing that information is info for a hacker that he has an existing account. Which he can probably try again in a couple of days... You might want to log that information internally but not expose that to the end user. How it is set, depends on what you use, default it is `true` and only `enabled` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, spring works with the user as http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html. So you need to find the code, where you transform your user entity to UserDetails. Maybe you are using some default mechanism like in memory or JDBC (check your http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html), in this case, you need to examine the docs/source code of this mechanism.

Comment: Yes we have the UserDetails class. When we login the user then we sets the UserDetails contructor with accountNonExpired = TRUE. So in our case, it comes as true. Is it expected?

Comment: It is expected if your system does not support locked, disabled or expired accounts. Probably user entity does not have a corresponding field as well as the database table. So all users are not locked/disabled/expired. If you want to add it then you need to add the corresponding attribute to the Table, create the field for User entity read it with your ORM and then pass the value to the UserDetails.

Comment: I will say, ok the UserDetails is used by Spring and in my code it was set to TRUE.